# Spring integration FTP: Stop file inbound-channel-adapter automatically when all source folder files are deleted

Tags: spring-integration

Is there any configuration settings/expression to stop channel adapter based on a condition (i.e, stop channel adapter when the source folder is empty)?

I can do this programatically as below but this approach won't work in my case.

Config:

```
 <file:inbound-channel-adapter prevent-duplicates="false" auto-startup="false" auto-create-directory="true" directory="${local.tmp.path}" id="fileInbound" channel="outputChannel" filename-pattern="*.xml">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="${local.transfer.interval}" max-messages-per-poll="100" />
   </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpFileOutboundAdapter" auto-create-directory="true" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" channel="outputChannel" charset="UTF-8" remote-directory="${ftp.path}">
    <sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />
            <property name="trapException" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Code:

```
fileInbound = context.getBean("fileInbound", SourcePollingChannelAdapter.class);
if (fileInbound.isRunning() && isSourcefolderEmpty()) {
     fileInbound.stop();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

1. In your `onSuccessExpression` use `payload` and add a `successChannel`.
2. Make the `successChannel` a `<publish-subsribe-channel/>`.
3. First subscriber (`order="1"`) is a `<service-activator/>` with the `payload.delete()`.
4. Second subscriber (`order="2"`) is a `<chain/>` that starts with a `<filter/>` that checks if the directory is empty...

.

```
 <chain ...>
     <filter expression="new java.io.File('/tmp/foo').list().length == 0" />
     <transformer expression="@fileInbound.stop()"/>
     <control-bus/>
 </chain>
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your advice. Is there any SpEL expression to use in filter to check whether a directory is empty() ?

Comment: How about `"new java.io.File('/tmp/foo').list().length == 0"` ?

Comment: Thanks Gary. its works well. In continuation to this task, I would like to start the channel adapter as well. something like this `<sftp:request-handler-advice-chain> ....<property name="onFailureExpression" value="'#{@fileInbound.isRunning()?: @fileInbound.start()" />` but this evaluates to "false' always. any suggestion please?

Comment: Something like `"@fileInbound.isRunning() ? 'ok' : @fileInbound.start() == null ? 'started' : 'never'"` ?